# Why can't I link this library using the GNU GCC Compiler on Windows (but on Linux I can)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I've been trying to link this CryptoPP library for some time now; no luck. Due to most of the resources relating to linking the CryptoPP library being on the Linux platform I temporarily installed Ubuntu on a VM and got CryptoPP working quite smoothly, however, as previously mentioned, it doesn't work on Windows.

I am using the CodeBlocks IDE on Windows 8 using the MinGW compiler.

- I already have the static CryptoPP .a file built.

My 2 attempts at linking the CrypoPP library have been:

A: 
 - Add the locations of the header files to the compiler and linker search directories (so it doesn't give me those "Head not found" errors)

- Add the library to the Link Libraries section (I added "libcryptopp")

I know that the compiler can see the Linked Library because when I change the name to the libcryptopp.a file to something else (libcryptopp1.a) it says "-llibcryptopp not found"

In the end I get a whole bunch of Undefined API error messages  :(

B: I then tried to add the header and library files to my compiler directory in suspicion of my IDE's search directory somehow failing me, this was not the case; I received the same Undefined API error messages.

I am tired of fighting this, if anyone could please leave some tips or point something out that I'm doing wrong I would be very grateful.

Comment: Did you build CryptoPP on Windows? Or if you have downloaded it, is it built for Windows?